# Remove elements n-1, n and n+1 based on a condition for n in a Haskell list

Tags: list, haskell, filter

So say I have a list of all integers from `2` to `20`.

```
[2 .. 20]
```

I want to filter through the list using a function `f x` (or is it a predicate? I'm not very used to all the terms used in Haskell programming). If the element at position `n` equals to true for this function `f`, I want to remove the elements at positions `n-1`, `n` and `n+1`.

Example:
Let's say that the element at position 4 in the list `[2 .. 20]`, which equals to `6`, equals to true for the function `f`. Then I want to remove the elements at position `3`, `4` and `5`, which equal to `5`, `6` and `7` respectively.
So my final list would look like:

```
[2,3,4,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

I am an inexperienced Haskell programmer, just playing around for fun. I have thought about using a lambda function as predicate but I am not quite sure how to go about it. I have also thought about using a function like `remove xs ys` that removes all elements in `xs` that is also a element of `ys`, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I realized that removing both adjacent elements is wrong in order to produce the result I wanted. Additionally, it might be better to just change the value of the affected elements (elements at positions `n` and `n-1`) to `0`, or tag/mark them in some other way, instead of removing them entirely. The reason for that is that I want to keep "removing" elements until the list no longer has any elements that fit the predicate (and their preceding elements). I only want to "remove" them from **the original list**.
Since my approach has changed so much from the original question, I will post a new one with to reflect my new approach. I want to thank you for all the responses and I have learned a lot from your answers. Thank you!

EDIT 2: Here is my new question: [Remove elements at positions n and n-1 in a Haskell list, when n fits a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185550/remove-elements-at-positions-n-and-n-1-in-a-haskell-list-when-n-fits-a-predicat)

Comment: For your remove function, the predicate is just a variable. I suggest learning pattern matching. BTW, this is a good task for learning advanced ist handling.

Comment: What if both the element at position 4 and the element at position 5 pass the predicate? Which elements would be removed? The elements at position 3, 4, 5 and 6?

Comment: You pointed straight to the point where haskell's lists suck a bit. AFAIK, there's no standard combinators to handle logical dependencies between elements. I only can suggest using explicit recursion or zippers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just pattern-match on multiple elements and apply your filter to the middle one.

```
eitherside :: (Int->Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
eitherside f (i1:i2:i3:is) = if (f i2) 
    then eitherside f is 
    else i1 : (eitherside f (i2:i3:is))
eitherside f is = is
*Main> eitherside (==4) [1..10]
[1,2,6,7,8,9,10]
*Main> eitherside (==5) [1..10]
[1,2,3,7,8,9,10]
*Main> eitherside (==6) [1..10]
[1,2,3,4,8,9,10]
```

NOT LIKE THIS (my original post):

```
eitherside :: (Int->Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
eitherside f (i1:i2:i3:is) = if (f i2) 
    then eitherside f is 
    else [i1,i2,i3] ++ (eitherside f is)
eitherside f is = is
*Main> eitherside (==5) [1..10]
[1,2,3,7,8,9,10]
```

This bad one happened to work for 5, but fails for 6 because I'm skipping it in the "else" branch.

Comment: Although the OP didn't specify what should happen in edge cases, `eitherside (==1) [1..10]` returning the original list doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I couldn't decide what was sensible - if you always want three removed then return the original list. Otherwise, you need a more complicated set of patterns to handle end-cases.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added a quite big edit in the OP, but this solution might work out anyway. I can't believe I didn't think of pattern-matching myself...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, though I'm sure there are more elegant ways.

The approach is to first map our list `[a]` to a list of triples `[(Maybe a, a, Maybe a)]`. (The `Maybe` comes into play because the first and last elements are missing a predecessor/successor respectively.)

We can then implement a filter in terms of a predicate `adjacentF` that we construct on this triple type. (Note that the filter you asked for is backwards compared to the standard `filter` -- you want to *remove* things when the predicate is true.)

```
preprocess :: [a] -> [(Maybe a, a, Maybe a)]
preprocess xs = zip3 (beforeXs xs) xs (afterXs xs)

beforeXs :: [a] -> [Maybe a]
beforeXs xs = Nothing : (map Just xs)

afterXs :: [a] -> [Maybe a]
afterXs xs = concat [(map Just (tail xs)), [Nothing]]

middle3 :: (a, b, c) -> b
middle3 (_,x,_) = x

myfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myfilter f xs = map middle3 $ filter (not . adjacentF) (preprocess xs)
    where
        maybeF = maybe False f
        adjacentF (x,y,z) = (maybeF x) || (f y) || (maybeF z)
```

This should give the desired results in general:

```
*Main> myfilter (==20) [1..20]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
*Main> myfilter (==1) [1..20]
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
*Main> myfilter (==5) [1..20]
[1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
*Main> myfilter (\x -> x >= 12 && x <= 14) [1..20]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,16,17,18,19,20]
*Main> myfilter even [1..20]
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution using little homebrew list zipper implementation:

```
-- List zipper (think of this as a standard library routine):
data LZ a = LZ [a] a [a] deriving (Show)

listToLZ :: [a] -> LZ a
listToLZ (h:t) = LZ [] h t

lzToList :: LZ a -> [a]
lzToList (LZ l p r) = reverse l ++ p:r

moveRight, remLeft, remRight, remHere :: LZ a -> LZ a
moveRight (LZ l t (t':r)) = LZ (t:l) t' r
remLeft (LZ l p r) = LZ (tail l) p r
remRight (LZ l p r) = LZ l p (tail r)
remHere (LZ l _ (p:r)) = LZ l p r

-- And there's how one use this:
-- <business code>
traverse :: (a -> Bool) -> LZ a -> LZ a
traverse _ a@(LZ _ _ []) = a
traverse pr a@(LZ _ p _) 
   | pr p = traverse pr $ remHere $ remRight $ remLeft a
   | True = traverse pr $ moveRight a
-- </business code>

main = let
  l = [1..20]
  l' = lzToList $ traverse (==4) $ listToLZ l
in
  print l'
```

Output:

[1,2,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that gets the jobe done, albeit probably not the most efficient:

```haskell
f p l = map snd $ filter (flip notElem indices . fst) l'
  where
    indices = concat [[i - 1, i, i + 1] | (i, _) <- filter (p . snd) l']
    l' = zip [0..] l
```

Or a little shorter using `findIndices` from `Data.List`:

```haskell
f p l = map snd $ filter (flip notElem indices . fst) $ zip [0..] l
  where indices = concat [[i - 1, i, i + 1] | i <- findIndices p l]
```

Testing:

```
*Main> f (\x -> x == 6 || x == 7) [2..20]
[2,3,4,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose the problem and look at the condition under which an element is kept: which is that the element at position `n` is kept iff the predicate is `False` at positions `n-1`, `n` and `n+1`.

This points to the following approach:

```
keep3 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
keep3 f xs = go xs bs
  where b0 = map f xs
        b1 = (tail b0) ++ [False]
        b2 = False : b0
        bs = zipWith (||) (zipWith (||) b0 b1) b2
        go [] _ = []
        go (x:xs) (b:bs) = if (not b) then x : go xs bs else go xs bs
```

Some explanatory points:

- `b0` is a list, having the same length as the list of elements whose n-th value is the value of the predicate evaluated on the n-th element of the list.
- `b1` is the same as `b0` but shifted one to the left; so its n-th value is the predicate evaluated on the `n+1`-th element of the list
- `b2` is the same as `b0` but shifted one to the right; so its n-th value is the predicate evaluated on the `n-1`-th element of the list
- `bs` is the logical or of the lists `b0`, `b1`, `b2` done element-wise and so is a list of booleans of the same length as `xs`. The n-th element of `bs` determines if the n-th element of `xs` should be kept or not.
- Note that the predicate is only evaluated once for each element of the list `xs`. Also I think the boundary cases are handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to capture the idea of the neighborhood of an item in a list.

```
-- A neighborhood of a point in a list 
data Neighborhood a = Neighborhood {
    predecessors :: ![a],
    point :: !a,
    successors :: ![a]
} deriving Show
```

We can compute the neighborhoods of a list easily by accumulating the predecessors as we traverse the list:

```
-- On long lists or infinite stream, this will leak memory (it keeps all the predecessors in memory)
neighborhoods :: [a] -> [Neighborhood a]
neighborhoods = neighborhoods' []
    where
        neighborhoods' _ [] = []
        neighborhoods' ps (x:ss) = (Neighborhood ps x ss):(neighborhoods' (x:ps) ss)
```

These neighborhoods will include all the predecessors and successors of each list item. It'll be convenient to be able to consider a smaller neighborhood `within` a small radius of each neighborhood. It'll also be convenient to be able to `enumerate` the neighborhood. (the definition of `interleave` is bellow, it visits the lists in alternating order.)

```
within :: Int -> Neighborhood a -> Neighborhood a
within r n = Neighborhood (take r . predecessors $ n) (point n) (take r . successors $ n)

enumerate :: Neighborhood a -> [a]
enumerate n = (point n):(interleave (successors n) (predecessors n))
```

Now we can easily ask for what we want - the items whose neighborhood of radius 1 doesn't contain a disallowed value. (`pows` and `log2` are defined below/)

```
main = do
    let disallowed = \x -> x == pow2s !! log2 x
    print . map point . filter (not . any disallowed . enumerate . within 1) . neighborhoods $ [2..20]
```

If we are going to work incrementally on very large lists, it'd be useful to be able to have the garbage collector collect predecessors from far outside the neighborhood. That would be an efficient version of:

```
neighborhoodsRadius n = map (within n) . neighborhoods
```

To get this efficiency, we need to cause the evaluation of the predecessors of the neighborhood to happen strictly. In the code below, the strict evaluation is accomplished by using a Data.Sequence.Seq as the accumulator as we traverse the list.

Here's complete running code:

```
module Main (
    pow2s,
    log2,
    main,

    interleave,
    Neighborhood (..),
    within,
    enumerate,  
    neighborhoods,
    neighborhoodsRadius,
) where

import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
import Data.Sequence ((<|))
import Data.Foldable (toList)

-- Interleave lists
interleave :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
interleave [] ys = ys
interleave (x:xs) ys = x:(interleave ys xs)


-- A neighborhood of a point in a list 
data Neighborhood a = Neighborhood {
    predecessors :: ![a],
    point :: !a,
    successors :: ![a]
} deriving Show

within :: Int -> Neighborhood a -> Neighborhood a
within r n = Neighborhood (take r . predecessors $ n) (point n) (take r . successors $ n)

enumerate :: Neighborhood a -> [a]
enumerate n = (point n):(interleave (successors n) (predecessors n))

-- On long lists or infinite stream, this will leak memory (it keeps all the predecessors in memory)
neighborhoods :: [a] -> [Neighborhood a]
neighborhoods = neighborhoods' []
    where
        neighborhoods' _ [] = []
        neighborhoods' ps (x:ss) = (Neighborhood ps x ss):(neighborhoods' (x:ps) ss)

-- This is better on long lists or infinite stream as it will cull the predecessors before recursing
neighborhoodsRadius :: Int -> [a] -> [Neighborhood a]
neighborhoodsRadius radius = neighborhoods' Seq.empty
    where
        neighborhoods' _ [] = []
        neighborhoods' ps (x:ss) =
            (Neighborhood (toList radiusPs) x radiusSs):(neighborhoods' (x <| radiusPs) ss)
                where
                    radiusPs = Seq.take radius ps
                    radiusSs = take radius ss

-- example
pow2s = iterate (*2) 1
log2 n = length . takeWhile (< n) $ pow2s

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let disallowed = \x -> x == pow2s !! log2 x
    print . map point . filter (not . any disallowed . enumerate . within 1) . neighborhoods $ [2..20]
    getLine
    let steps = map (print . point) . filter (not . any disallowed . enumerate) . neighborhoodsRadius 1 $ [2..]
    sequence_ steps
```