# Remove elements at positions n and n-1 in a Haskell list, when n fits a predicate

Tags: list, haskell, predicate

Say I have a list of all the integers from `2` to `20`.

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

I also have a function `f x` that returns either `True` or `False`. When I apply this function to the element at position `n` and it equals to `True`, I want to remove it and its precedent element (which is the element at position `n-1`). I want to keep doing this until the list is empty of elements for which the function equals to `True`, as well as their preceding elements.

Example:
Let's say that the element at position `11`, which equals to `13`, fits the predicate. I then want to remove the element at position `10`, which equals to `12`, as well. After that my final list would be:

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

Let's also say that the elements at position `4`, `8` as well as `15` are the only elements (apart from the element at position `13`) that fit the predicate. After removing them and their preceding elements my final list would look like:

```
[2,3,4,7,8,11,14,15,18,19,20]
```

I'm an inexperienced Haskell programmer, and just playing around for fun. I thought of using some kind of lambda function as predicate to a filter, or creating a function like `listRemove xs ys` that removes all elements of `xs` that are also an element of `ys`, but I feel kind of lost on both.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: what I am trying to do is to solve a [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problem, namely [#179](http://projecteuler.net/problem=179). The predicate `f x` is to check whether `x` is a prime number or not. Therefore I can surely say that no corner cases exists – e.g. there are no cases such as `[x, x, t, t]` where `t` is a number for which the predicate holds, since there exists no two consecutive integers that are both prime except for `2` and `3`, which I can easily handle in my solution. Instead, the closest you can get is `[x, t, x, t]`, and in that case I want to remove all of those elements.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's changed since your [previous, similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21182206/3015232). You seem to have some purpose in mind but you're not sharing that with us - perhaps you could explain the original problem, since there may be an elegant way of solving that directly. Please read about [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242387).

Comment: On the face of it, you can slightly rehash the answers to your previous question, but your edit to your previous question introducing this one includes more ideas than this does. You mentioned replacing or editing values. If you wanted to replace 19 and 20 with 20*5 because 20 satisfies your predicate, did you want to check the new 100 against your predicate too? Have you tried out the code the answerers to your old question gave?

Comment: Your remove operation isn't well defined, you have to specify an order. What about the corner case (x,x,t,t), where `t` are elements where the predicate holds? Should it return (), since (x,x,t,t) -> (x,t) -> () [we remove the inner (x,t)] , or (x,x) [we remove (t,t)]?

Comment: @Zeta Another good point. Another reason to let on about the problem context. (I think you meant square brackets, though.)

Comment: @chunksOf50: The format wasn't Haskell specific, just want to show an ordered set.

Comment: I agree with @chunksOf50. Your new question is very similar to your previous question, and a very small change to the given answers would solve this problem as well. Let us see the real problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, I intentionally was vague about my problem since it's a [Project Euler problem](http://projecteuler.net), and therefore didn't want to spoil the problem for anyone else. However, I now realize that my solution isn't very optimal at all, so I might as well post it.

I found out (after some thinking) that Richard Huxton's answer to my previous question works for my new approach as well, so you are right: I can tweak the answers to my previous question to fit my new approach. I probably should have thought more before I posted this question.

Comment: @ChristianPersson: In this case you should add the problem's number.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved** *"Remove elements at positions n and n-1 in a Haskell list, when n fits a predicate"*

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' f xs = map (\i -> xs!!i) $
                 [i | i <- [0 .. s], fit i && (i >= s || fit (i+1))]
               where s = length xs - 1
                     fit i = not (f (xs!!i))
```

usage

```
*Main> filter' (==4) [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,5,6]

*Main> filter' (\n -> n `mod` 7 == 0) [1..23]
[1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,19,22,23]

*Main> filter' (\n -> n `elem` [4,5,6]) [1..10]
[1,2,7,8,9,10]
```

With **O(n)** cost may be

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], Bool)
filter' _  [] = ([], False)
filter' f [x] = if f x then ([], True) else ([x], False)
filter' f (y:xs) = case filter' f xs of
                    (xs', True)  -> (xs', f y)
                    (xs', False) -> if f y then (xs', True) else (y:xs', False)
```

using standar functions

```
filter' f xs = filter (not.f) $ map fst $ filter (not.f.snd) $ zip xs $ tail xs ++ [last xs]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have:

```
disallowed :: Int -> bool
-- A function that matches your example
disallowed x = elem x [6, 10, 13, 17]
```

What you want is just

```
import Data.List (tails)

map head . filter (not . any disallowed . take 2) . filter (not . null) . tails $ [2..20]
```

If you want to give it a name:

```
filterWithTails :: ([a] -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterWithTails f = map head . filter f . filter (not . null) . tails

filterWithTails (not . any disallowed . take 2) [2..20]
```

`(not . any disallowed . take 2)` is how you want to filter a list considering the remainder of the list when filtering. It'd be hard to give a better name than the composition of the functions that make it up.